# Lightdm active user indication removed

Tags: 13.10, lightdm, gnome-screensaver

Just updated to 13.10 and I notice the Lightdm sign in screen on a multi-user system no longer indicates which users are already logged in. Previously active users were listed in bold text.

Comment: GDM doesn't indicate active users either anymore so this must be a change some where else than the Display Managers.This is on Xubuntu.

Comment: I've replaced gnome-screensaver with light-locker and now occasionally the system indicates which accounts in the login screen of lightdm are active. I'm yet to notice a pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated lightdm-gtk-greeter to 1.7.1 and the active sessions are again indicated in bold text. I was previously on the default 1.6.1.